# Django - NoReverseMatch at /.... Reverse for ... with arguments ("",52)

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, url-routing

Have looked through a lot of similar NoReverseMatch Errors and couldn't solve my problem. This is in Django.

I keep getting:
NoReverseMatch at /equipment32
Reverse for 'equipment' with arguments '('', 32)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['equipment(?P<equipment_id>[0-9]+)$']

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Albert\Desktop\HARVARD CS50\tracker_django\tracker\views.py", line 128, in equipment
    return render(request, "jobs/equipment.html", context)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 443, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 87, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 677, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
```

This is my template, job.html, that generates the links:

```
 <table style="width: 900px">
        <caption style="font-size: 25px">Equipment in Scope</caption>
        <a href="#equipment_form" style="font-size: 20px">Add Equipment</a>
        <tr>
          <th>Site ID</th>
          <th>Equipment Type</th>
          <th>Manufacturer</th>
          <th>Model</th>
          <th>Test Sheet</th>

        </tr>
        {% for equipment in equipments %}

              <tr>

                  {% csrf_token %}
                  <td><a href="{% url 'equipment' equipment.id %}">{{equipment.site_id}}</a></td>
                  <td>{{equipment.template.classification}}</td>
                  <td>{{equipment.manufacturer}}</td>
                  <td>{{equipment.model}}</td>
                  <td><a href="www.drive.google.com">Test Sheet</td>
              </tr>

        {% empty %}
              <li>No Equipment</li>
        {% endfor %}
</table> <br>
```

This seems to load fine and create links for each equipment object. Here's my urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views, constructors
from .models import Job, FSR, Template, Equipment, TestEquipment


urlpatterns = [
     path("equipment<int:equipment_id>", views.equipment, name="equipment"),
]
```

This url is supposed to link to views.equipment; here it is:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

from .models import Job, FSR, Template, Equipment, TestEquipment

def equipment(request, equipment_id):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, "jobs/login.html", {"message": None})
    try:
        equipment=Equipment.objects.get(pk=equipment_id)
    except Equipment.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Equipment does not exist.")
    context = {
        "equipment": equipment,
        "templates": Template.objects.all(),
        "test_equipments": equipment.template.recommended_test_equipment.all(),
    }
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, "jobs/equipment.html", context)
```

which should generate my actual equipment.html:

```
{% extends "jobs/base.html"%}

{% block title %}
  {{equipment.site_id}}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
      <h1 style = "text-align: center">{{equipment.site_id}} ({{equipment.template.classification}})</h1>

      <style>table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}</style>
      <table style="width:900px">
        <caption style="font-size: 25px">Equipment Properties</caption>
        <tr>
          <td>Equipment Type</td>
          <td><b>{{equipment.template.classification}}</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Job Site ID or Name</td>
          <td><b>{{equipment.site_id}}</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Manufacturer</td>
          <td><b>{{equipment.manufacturer}}</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Model</td>
          <td><b>{{equipment.model}}</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Link to Manual</td>
          <td><a href="https://www.eaton.com"><b>{{equipment.manual}}</b></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Link to Item Folder</td>
          <td><a><b>{{equipment.template.cloud_link}}</b></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Equipment Questions</td>
          <td><a><b>{{equipment.template.equipment_questions}}</b></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Answers</td>
          <!-- <form action="{% url 'equipment' job.id equipment.id%}" method="post">
          <td><a><b><textarea id="scope" name="scope" rows="4" cols="55" >{{ equipment.equipment_answers }}</textarea><input type="submit" value="Confirm Answers">
          <input type="reset"></b></a></td>
          </form> -->
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Scope for This Equipment</td>
          <td><a><b>{{equipment.scope}}</b></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Additional Notes</td>
          <td><a><b>{{equipment.notes}}</b></a></td>
        </tr>
      </table><br>


        <h3>Recommended Test Equpiment</h3>

        <ul>
            {% for test_equipment in test_equipments %}
                <li>

                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ test_equipment }}

                </li>
            {% empty %}
                <li>No Equipment</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>



      <button onclick="goBack()">Back to Job Page</button>
      <script>
        function goBack() {
          window.history.back();
        }
      </script>


{% endblock %}
```

I don't understand why it seems to be asking for two arguments equipment("", 35) because the views function only takes in equipment_id. Any help is very greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your template `equipment.html` you provided two argument just remove `job.id`. though it is commented but it should be proper `urlpattern`

```
<form action="{% url 'equipment' equipment.id%}" method="post">
          <td><a><b><textarea id="scope" name="scope" rows="4" cols="55" >{{ equipment.equipment_answers }}</textarea><input type="submit" value="Confirm Answers">
          <input type="reset"></b></a></td>
          </form>
```

Comment: Wow! I deleted that form which I had commented out earlier and it works. Why would the commented out html throw an error. Kind of irritating but thanks so much. I was pulling my hair out

Comment: django url resolver always process url tag weather it commented or not. Thanks please upvote.And you can also verify answer.

Comment: Very good to know. Thanks; I upvoted but I don't have "15 reputation" so it doesn't show up. Just opened an account here

Answer (score 1):

My issue was in the commented out section of the equipment.html code. I had a commented out section that included:

```
 <form action="{% url 'equipment' equipment.id job.id method="post" %}>....
```

It turns out that django url resolver always processes url tags whether commented or not and the above html code was attempting to send the url 2 arguments while my url path only takes 1 argument.